# Populate smartautocomplete on text box focus

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I am using smartautocomplete. It is working perfectly when i searched for any data and also working perfectly on scroll. 
Now i am trying when user click on textbox then it will show by default autocomplete box but i am not able to open default autocomplete on focus.
i am using smartautocomplete.js.
My code is as below :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    //Input for testing purposes
    $("#inp").smartautocomplete({
        getDataFunc: getData,
        pageSize: 15,
        autoFocus: true,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#inp').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#inp1').val(ui.item.value);
            //$('#<%=hdnUserID.ClientID%>').val(ui.item.id)
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
        }
    }).focus(function () {
       //what to write here so i can get default autocomplete value on focus
    });
});


//Function the SA plugin called when data is needed. 
//var getData = function (input, pageIndex, pageSize, callback) {
var getData = function (input, pageIndex, pageSize, callback) {
    //In this example I use a WebMethod, but you can call anything from a local source to any web service.
    //url: "../../../Base/BindStateMaster?pageSize=10&pageNum=1&CountryCode=" + ParentddlValue,
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../../Base/BindCountryMasterAuto",
        data: "{'input':'" + input + "','pageIndex':'" + pageIndex + "','pageSize':'" + pageSize + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
        success: function (response) {

            if (response) {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                //Data is assumed to be received in a {label: , value: , ...} form, as needed by jqueryUI autocomplete. Of course, if you change the _renderItem function, you are free to modify this as you want
                response = $.map(response.Data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.text,
                        value: item.id
                    }
                });
                callback(response);
            }
            else callback();
        }

    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    $(function() {
        $('#id').autocomplete({
            source: ["your source array",

                    ],
            minLength: 0
        }).focus(function(){            
            $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
// or $(this).autocomplete("search", $(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks neo but i tried with this also but still autocomplete is not populating on focus. and i am using smartautocomplete.

Comment: and the code which you mentioned will work for autocomplete plugin. i am using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325719/JQueryUI-smartAutocomplete